Android - Google play staged rollout AppUpdateInfo
I have an Android Application that I am planning to do a staged rollout on Google Play for release (10%,20%... 100%).
In my Android App start-up, I will check with Google Play API appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo to check if there is an update available?
Buy say, if user is not in the staged roll-out will that user get "App Update Available" or "App Upto date"?
I checked the documentation but no confirmation on this documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#update_readiness

The user will get App Up to date until they is in the stage rollout.
